# Probability Based on a Grid of Lights

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry, geometric-probability

The question is as follows :

A grid of $n\times n$ ($n\ge 3$) lights is connected to a switch in such a way that each light has a $50\%$ chance of lighting up when switched on. What is the probability that we see a **closed curve** after turning on the switch?

1. A closed curve is basically a set of any number of *lines* that enclose an area (containing at least one light). The *lines* could be vertical, horizontal, or diagonal only (that is, making angles $0°, 90°$ or $45°$ with the horizontal), otherwise the curve would not be closed.
2. A *line* is a line segment joining two illuminated lights.
3. We only say a closed curve is formed, when all the lights except the ones that make up the boundary of the shape are switched **off**.
4. To check if any configuration satisfies these conditions, connect all the lights (that you claim to be part of the boundary of a shape) through *lines*. If there’s any other illuminated light left out, then this configuration is invalid.

5. *Every* illuminated light must be immediately next to at least one of the grid points that the curve encloses. As an example for what ‘immediately next to’ means, consider the $5\times5$ grid:  $$\begin{matrix} 1&2&3&4&5 \\ 6& \color{blue}7 & \color{blue}8 &\color{blue}9 &10 \\ 11&\color{blue}{12} &\color{red}{13} & \color{blue}{14} & 15   \\16 & \color{blue}{17}&\color{blue}{18}&\color{blue}{19} &20 \\ 21&22&23&24&25 \end{matrix} $$
   Here, the blue lights are immediately next to $13$.

This problem essentially comes down to counting the total number of such closed curves in an $n\times n$ grid. So I figured I might as well start off with the easy part.

Now, every single configuration of the grid occurs with an equal probability of $P=\frac{1}{2^{n^2}}$ (as there are a total of $2^{n^2}$ cases possible). So, the required probability will be the number of possible closed curves $\space \times P$. How can I determine all the closed curves?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Suppose you have a 3x3 grid. Which configurations of lights satisfy the two conditions? Suppose the lights are: $$\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\end{matrix}$$ which collection of lights must be on to be a closed curve? Would $\{1,2,4,5\}$ count? What about $\{2,4,6,8\}$?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Think of it like connecting the points by lines. ${1,2,4,5}$ would not count because it does not enclose any other number, although ${2,4,6,8}$ is perfectly fine.

Comment: What about $\{2,7,9\}$? Does that still enclose $5$? Or $\{2,7,8,9\}$?

Comment: The lines should only be vertical, horizontal or diagonal, i.e. making angles $0°,90°$ or $45°$ with the horizontal. So no, none of those count.

Comment: What about $\{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9\}$? That still encloses $5$, but the corners are not strictly needed, as you already said that $\{2,4,6,8\}$ was fine.

Comment: Yup, that’s a square which encloses 5 and is acceptable.

Comment: @Tavish In 4), you should say "left out" instead of "left off" lol

Comment: @mathworker21 LOL.

Comment: What you want to count is the number of self-avoiding polygons in a square lattice (with an additional degree of freedom to go diagonal), I don't think a closed-form formula for this exists

Comment: @SagarM Any approximations are welcome too.

Comment: @Tavish, in the 4x4 grid of Interstellar's answer, do you allow e.g. 1,2,3,4,7,11,10,9,5?  by your definition it's still a closed curves of lines, but intuitively this is also a square plus extra (the 4).

Comment: Would it be possible to simplify the problem by considering only the 'tightest closed curves'?  'Tightest' meaning that if it would be impossible to remove any on-light from a curve, without it losing its status of 'closed curve'.  Otherwise, following antkam's comments, in the 4x4 problem and for enclosing 6, would {1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12, 16, 11, 15, 10, 14, 13, 9, 5, back to 1} or {5, 2, 7, 8, 7 again, 10, back to 5} also both be valid?

Comment: @antkam  Actually, the three configurations you and Chris proposed are all invalid. I have added a new condition that takes care of this, which will hopefully make the problem somewhat easier. I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: @Chris You may want to check my edit.

Comment: @Tavish Awesome!  (It might be worth also adding the condition that the enclosed grid area must be connex, i.e. that any pair of grid points enclosed by a closed curved can be connected by a 'line-of-off-lights'?  This would remove cases such as {12 and 19} being enclosed by {11,7,13,14,20,24,18,17})

Comment: @Chris Concavities are allowed, too.

Comment: @Tavish - The new condition (5) is very natural -- I was honestly surprised when you allowed my curve a week ago. :) Anyway, with condition (5) added, the answer by Interstellar is a very good starting point.  The counting is still not closed form, but at least it should be doable by computer now: First pick the set of point(s) you want to enclose (there are an exponential number of such sets), then for each set figure out the REQUIRED points and the OPTIONAL (corner) points, then do the math in Interstellar's answer.

Comment: [cont'd] If the enclosed points must be contiguous, the counting is now theoretically doable.  If the enclosed points can be far apart, however, then the counting is still non obvious.  E.g. if there are two enclosed points and they are distance $10$ apart, then each point has to be enclosed by $4$ to $8$ neighbors, but then there are many, _many_ ways to connect the two neighborhoods (and still satisfy your definition of closed curve).

Comment: @antkam The computation is nice and all, but what I’m really interested in is the mathematical bit (approximations, bounds, maybe the limit as 
$n$
 gets very large, the average area enclosed by a curve, etc.). Is there a way of counting such sets of, at least, contiguous points, given a value of n?

Answer (score 2):

This is just a way to start thinking about it, not a full solution.

Let's start with smaller numbers and see what happens.  For $3\times 3$ grids:

$$\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 & 9\end{matrix}$$ 
there are $2^4 = 16$ configurations that work. You need at least $\{2,4,6,8\}$ and you may have any of the following also: $\{1,3,7,9\}$.

So, that is $\dfrac{2^4}{2^9} = \dfrac{1}{32}$.

For a $4\times 4$ grid:

$$\begin{matrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\ 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\ 13 & 14 & 15 & 16\end{matrix}$$

There are $2^4$ configurations each to surround $6,7,10,11$. There are $2^4$ ways to surround any pair $(6,7), (6,10), (7,11), (10,11)$. For $(6,11)$ or $(7,10)$, you can surround them by $2,5,7,10,12,15$ or $3,6,8,9,11,14$ respectively. And there are $2^6$ ways to choose from the corners of the enclosure. Consider a configuration surrounding $(6,7,10)$. You need at least $2,3,5,8,9,11,14$, but you may include any of $1,4,12,13,15$, so there are $2^5$ ways to surround them, and similarly for $(6,7,11), (7,10,11), (6,10,11)$. And finally, if you have all four of the center ones surrounded, you need at least $2,3,5,8,9,12,14,15,16$, and you may or may not include $1,4,13,16$ at your whim.

So, that is:

$$\frac{4\cdot 2^4+4\cdot 2^4 + 2\cdot 2^6 + 4\cdot 2^5+2^4}{2^{16}} = \dfrac{25}{4096}$$

I am not seeing an easy pattern to extend this. As the enclosed area in the center become more complicated, it seems the number of possible ways to surround it becomes more complicated as well.

This appears closely related to the number of ways to claim an area in Go.

Comment: Note: I am not sure about some configurations. For example, does $1,3,7,9$ surround $5$ in the $3\times 3$ grid? Or does it need to include $2,4,6,8$?

Comment: It does need to include $ 2,4,6,8$ otherwise the shape wouldn’t look continuous. It shouldn’t have any holes.

Comment: The best I can think of is an $n\times n$ grid contains 4 distinct $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ grids. So, you may be able to find some sort of recursion.

Comment: For $(6,11)$, the optional lights are $1,3,8,9,14,16$.

Comment: The problem with the recursive approach is to figure out how to include the remaining $2n-1$ lights with the already existing curves in the $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ grid.

Comment: Consider the four overlapping $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ grids. Each takes a corner of the original $n\times n$ grid. Use Inclusion/Exclusion to find all of the patterns that are in the sum of the four minus the overlap of any two grids, plus the overlap of any three grids, minus the overlap of all four grids. This means possibly a system of recursive formulas? And I'm not sure what to do about shapes that are too big to fit in an $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ grid but not too big for an $n\times n$ grid.

Comment: +1 and esp. the Go mention.  the twist is i dont know if the OP means to allow a closed curve if it encloses ("captures") two disconnected areas.  e.g. something like two copies of 2,4,6,8 (of the 3x3 grid) connected by a single long line.  still, playing Go and having a math background might be positively correlated (esp. in the West), so there might have been some math/Go people who have thought about this already.

Comment: Hmm, according to comment below OP, another way to enclose 6 would be 1,2,3,4,7,11,10,9,5.  so if "extras" (e.g. 4 here) are allowed then the computation in this answer is missing some cases, i.e. there are $>2^4$ ways to enclose 6.  these extras potentially make the problem _much_ harder...

Comment: OP changed the question by adding condition 5.  With this new condition, 1,2,3,4,7,11,10,9,5 is no longer allowed, and this answer is now a great starting point.